# Trouble Stacking Ionic Cards

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to have ionic cards that rotate on my site. I need them to stack vertically but I can't get them to stack unless the front and back of the cards stack as well which leaves a large margin between vertical cards.

Codepen where cards are overlapping instead of stacking relative to the bottom of the previous card 
https://codepen.io/Froelund/pen/gppBvX

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {})
.directive('flipContainer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            $scope.flip = function() {
                $elem.toggleClass('flip');
            }
        }
    };
 });
```

Comment: transform-origin ?

Answer (score 0):

Made the front relative and the back absolute and now I have the desired effect.

```
.front {
  position: relative;
}

.back {
  position: absolue;
}
```